Portobello looking mushrooms growing in yard
Sorry, I know this is probably kind of a lame question for this forum, but I live in Northeast MA, and it has been a mix of hot, sunny, and wet over the past few weeks. These guys started popping up in my garden in the past few days. I went to remove them, and I noticed they were very familiar-looking—large caps, black undersides, some with big white fleshy stalks some without (ie: photos).
I know very little about mushrooms, aside from the basics and what I cook with. These to me looked like portobello (stalks aside), but I assume that is not the case.
Did some "foraging" on the internet, hard to find what these are.
Either way, they were delicious in my morning omelette (jk).



Probably a fieldcap, wine-cap, or maybe a widow, but I can't narrow it down enough. Could you go out and take closer up photos? Look for small ones, and large ones, get closeups of their undersides and stems, as well as "roots". A good picture of the top is important as well.

Obligatory - don't eat fungi that are not positively identified by a local expert, and certainly not ones ID'd over the internet, even if the person seemingly knows what they are talking about.

too late burp - next question, how do I get my dog to stop talking me?
